# How to validate the server certificate and trust using node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a requirement to validate the certificate from the https endpoint URL and ensure it is valid and can be trusted before making post call using node.js. The endpoint url I have is like `https://example.org/abc`.

I could get the certificate using `res.socket.getPeerCertificate()`. I get the expiry date, CN etc details. But I'm not sure how to ensure that it can be trusted, besides additional requirement says, I need to ensure the certificate has not been revoked by checking the Certificate Revocation List Distribution Point (CRLDP).

I am fairly new to node.js, and need some help/tips how to achieve the above said validations. I only have the https endpoint url.

Thanks -
Raj

Comment: Must you use nodejs ?  An easier solution would be to use nginx to be your TLS terminator so nodejs can be oblivious to all the very complex security issues ... outside world  <-->  nginx <--> nodejs

Comment: yes, nodejs is the requirement

Comment: @ScottStensland How in the world is using nginx supposed to help with nodejs making a **client HTTP** request to another service?